# Remove tags in [] with regex

Tags: c#, regex

As an example I have this content

```
<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[<tag3>[<tag4>TAB1</tag4>]</tag3>]</tab1>
<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[<tag3>[<tag5></tag5><tag4>TAB2</tag4>]</tag3>]</tab1>
```

I want this return

```
<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[[TAB1]]</tab1>
<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[[TAB2]]</tab1>
```

I tried

```
Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", string.Empty)
```

but this removed all tags. I need to remove only those that are within `[]`.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help guys there. I ended up doing otherwise, because I could not make any of the following ways: for I have random tags and variable names.

```
 public static string PrepareDocument(string input, int posBase = 0)
        {
            int indexFistOpen = input.IndexOf('[', posBase);
            int indexFistClose = input.IndexOf(']', indexFistOpen);
            int indexLastClose = input.IndexOf(']', indexFistClose + 1);
            int tagLength = (indexLastClose - indexFistOpen) + 1;

            var txWithTags = input.Substring(indexFistOpen, tagLength);
            var text = Regex.Replace(txWithTags, "<.*?>", string.Empty);

            input = input.Remove(indexFistOpen, tagLength);
            input = input.Insert(indexFistOpen, text);

            posBase = input.IndexOf(text, posBase) + text.Length;
            if (input.IndexOf('[', posBase) > -1)
            {
                input = PrepareDocument(input, posBase);
            }

            return input;
        }
```

Comment: I try this Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", string.Empty). Bus this remove all tags. I need to remove only those that are within []

Answer (score 3):

A way consists to find the outer-most square brackets and to remove only tags in the matched parts.

To do that you need to use [balancing groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#balancing_group_definition) to find substrings in nested (or not) brackets. Then all you need is to delegate the replacement to a function with [`MatchEvaluator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a fixed string.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string html = "<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[<tag3>[<tag4>TAB1</tag4>]</tag3>]</tab1>\n"
                + "<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[<tag3>[<tag5></tag5><tag4>TAB2</tag4>]</tag3>]</tab1>";

    string pattern = @"\[(?>[^][]+|(?<open>\[)|(?<close-open>]))*(?(open)(?!))]";
    MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(RemoveTags);

    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(html, pattern, evaluator));      
}

public static string RemoveTags(Match match)
{
    return Regex.Replace(match.Value, @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty);   
}
```

An other way that can be more performant (since C# is a compiled language) is to write your own string parser with basic string manipulations. All you need is a counter to know when the square brackets are balanced. When an opening bracket is found you increment the counter, when a closing bracket is found you decrement the counter, when the counter is equal to zero, the brackets are balanced. (note that this is more or less what the balancing group pattern does).

Answer (score 2):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[)(</?tag\d>)+|(</?tag\d>)+(?=\])");

var src1 = "<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[<tag3>[<tag4>TAB1</tag4>]</tag3>]</tab1>";
var src2 = "<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[<tag3>[<tag5></tag5><tag4>TAB2</tag4>]</tag3>]</tab1>";

var result1 = regex.Replace(src1, "");
var result2 = regex.Replace(src2, "");
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result]

---

There is probably a less verbose way of writing the regex. Anyway, I am using the lookbefore `(?<=\[)` and lookahead `(?=\])` assertions to determine when to match the tag elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex is a good solution but it's about 3 times slower then this method that've just wrote:

```
    static string removeTagsInBrackets(string input)
    {            
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
        bool insideBrackets = false;
        bool insideTag = false; char c;
        int indexOfLast = input.LastIndexOf(']');
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            c = input[i];
            if (c == '[') { insideBrackets = true; sb.Append(c); continue; }
            if (i == indexOfLast) { insideBrackets = false; sb.Append(c); continue; }
            if (c == '<' || c == '>') { insideTag = !insideTag; }
            if (insideBrackets) if (insideTag || (!insideTag && c == '>')) continue;
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Usage:

```
        string s = @"<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[<tag3>[<tag5></tag5><tag4>TAB2</tag4>]</tag3>]</tab1>";
        var result = removeTagsInBrackets(s);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output : `<tag1><tag2>Test</tag2>[[TAB2]]</tab1>`

Check also : [**Test on performance**](http://i.gyazo.com/d621ccffbbddfb9906581c3ea1decbac.png)